# Uninstall php/apache packages which were installed from source

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, uninstall

I recently installed php and apache from **source distribution** on my ubuntu(amazon ec2) instance. Now, I want to remove them. But didn't get a way to do that. Can anyone please help me show should be uninstall them.

Or If I need to delete files/directories manually, is there any way to find which were installed for a package? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dpkg -r apache2` or `dpkg -r php5` (You will need to adjust according to your version)

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the original compiled source directory somewhere you may be able to use `sudo make uninstall` in each directory which (in theory) should remove all of the files installed.

Note I say in theory because it's not guaranteed the Makefile has proper provision for "uninstalling" in this way. Generally the recommendation is to use packages shipped with the distribution unless you're fully aware of what you're doing and have a strategy for handling upgrades & uninstalling applications installed this way.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I  searched and found such tips to use 'make uninstall', but seems like its not available on either of the source distributions. Is there any alternative commands as well?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this command to remove them.

> apt-get remove apache2 php5

Comment: that is the command to remove binary distribution, not source distribution. I need a solution for package installed from source code with 'make' command.

Answer (score -1):

Use this commant to remove apache server and php (Worked for me):

```
sudo yum remove httpd* php*
```

See this question too (Answer from "Rijas Madurakuzhi"):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206795/how-to-install-php5-6-in-amazon-linux

Comment: yum will not work on ubuntu and this will not remove software installed from source.

Comment: It's working but on Amazon Linux Ubuntu 14.04! Or?

Comment: @gera http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Comment: @GeraldSchneider

Comment: Quote from your link: `If you are trying to set up a LAMP web server on an Ubuntu instance, this tutorial will not work for you. These procedures are intended for use with Amazon Linux`